# Making Discord bot command case insensitive?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, case-sensitive

I created a "roleinfo" command for my discord bot. I'm not sure how to make the role search case insensitive. See my code below:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    //Message checks
    if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("You must specify a role name");

    //Grab args and specify as rolename
    let roleName = `${args[0]}`

    //@rolename
    let roleMention = message.guild.roles.find(roles => roles.name === roleName)

    let rolefind = message.guild.roles.find(roles => roles.name === roleName)
    if (!rolefind) return message.channel.send(`Can't find role ${args[0]}`);

    //Filter members for role
    let membersWithRole = message.guild.members.filter(member => {
        return member.roles.find(roles => roles.name === roleName);
    }).map(member => {
        return member.user.username;
    })

    let serverembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor("#FFD700")
        .addField("Role name", roleMention)
        .addField("Number of users with the role", rolefind.members.size)
        .addField("Users with the role", membersWithRole.join("\n"))


    message.channel.send(serverembed);
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "roleinfo",
    usage: "``prefix`` roleinfo or ``prefix`` roleinfo rolename",
    description: "Displays detailed role information",
}
```

I know I have to use .toLowerCase() or .toUpperCase() but i'm not sure how/where in this scenario. Could anyone help me out? Will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: i guess you use .toLowerCase before you compare them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said yourself, just do

```
roleMention = message.guild.roles.find(roles => roles.name.toLowerCase() === roleName.toLowerCase())
```

That would make out of :

```
'Role-name' === 'Role-NAME'

'role-name' === 'role-name'
```

Comment: Thanks! Everywhere there is `roles.name` or `roleName` i just added `.toLowercase()`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this would work for you? (Dry-coded, YMMV.)

The idea is to use `.toLowerCase()` in the two filtering statements that look at role names, both in the global list of roles and in the per-member role list.

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  const roleName = args[0];
  //Message checks
  if (!roleName) return message.channel.send("You must specify a role name");

  const roleFind = message.guild.roles.find(roles => roles.name.toLowerCase() === roleName.toLowerCase());
  if (!roleFind) return message.channel.send(`Can't find role ${roleName}`);

  const memberNamesWithRole = [];
  message.guild.members.forEach(member => {
    if (member.roles.some(memberRole => memberRole.name.toLowerCase() === roleName.toLowerCase())) {
      memberNamesWithRole.push(member.user.username);
    }
  });

  const serverembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor("#FFD700")
    .addField("Role name", roleName)
    .addField("Number of users with the role", memberNamesWithRole.length)
    .addField("Users with the role", memberNamesWithRole.join("\n"));

  message.channel.send(serverembed);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using .toLowerCase() or .toUpperCase() can produce issues about special Unicode characters.

So, use : String.prototype.localeCompare()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

And for the change you juste need to edit the delegate `roles => roles.name === roleName`

Comment: I don't think Discord allows special characters in their roles anyway